# Whats the definition and name of the "No development methodology"

Tags: methodology

I am struggling with finding a good solid name for development processes that is described best as either "Non existing", "Homegrown" or "We whipped it out ourselves and it rocks".

I need this name so I can create a comparison between other development methodologies like agile and waterfall.

How do you call this type of development methodology? Please provide an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Ad hoc - any development process that lacks a process.  Alternatively you can call it "maturity model level 0".  I've frequently referred to that methodology as "Success by accident"

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I guess "Ad hoc" will do, but I really like the "Success by accident" version, thanks.

Comment: "Homebrew" is sometimes used to describe something knocked together on the fly internally

Comment: Note that intentionally stirring up negative sentiment in a prospective customer may sometimes backfire. Ad-hoc processes tend to be unique (or quirky) for each organization, so a careful study of the "current process" would be needed to identify the strengths and weaknesses of each ad-hoc organization, instead of being generalized into a single vilified model.

Comment: How about indigenous?

Answer (score 2):

I've always gone with 'Chaos' - but that has been scarily accurate in my situation.  If you are trying to explain it to management, I would simply call it 'the current process'.

Comment: * 'the current (lack of) process' :D

Answer (score 2):

In comparison I use "JFDI" - just f* do it or "JDI" - just do it (more polite one, I use this when presenting to students)

Comment: Hey Jelena, welcome to Project Management SE. Can you provide a more in-depth explanation as requested by the asker? In general, we look for answers that help explain the reasoning behind something, not just hit and run posts. See [answer] for details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd opt for a rather neutral descriptor that doesn't attach any positive or negative connotations to the approach. Particularly if you're completing a comparison exercise whereby the pro's and con's of each approach should be outlined.

I've used 'customized' and 'bespoke' as neutral descriptors for something that's not a traditionally recognized methodology but is, through either tried and tested experience or to fulfill the specific needs of the organisation that uses it, an existing approach.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no development without the methodology. Development process always has some rules by which it is built. Even if seemingly there are no rules, "no rules" is also a rule. If you have one of that kind of process with minimal regulation, it looks like "[Cowboy coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding)", where developers have minimum constraint from developing process.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago, I attended a talk given by Grady Booch, and he referred to this type of development process as "heroic" I.e. any success was dependent on the great efforts of the participants.

I have always liked that description, as the lack of a process shouldn't detract from the talents of the team members.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [CMMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability_Maturity_Model) definition of level 1 maturity:

> **Level 1 - Initial (Chaotic)**
>
> It is characteristic of processes at this level that they are (typically) undocumented and in a state of dynamic change, tending to be driven in an ad hoc, uncontrolled and reactive manner by users or events. This provides a chaotic or unstable environment for the processes.

Answer (score 2):

**Ad-hoc.**

It means, "for this"; the processes have been created specifically for the situation at hand. It can also rock, especially for small teams. I've worked with a lot of start-ups and find their processes tend to be more similar to Lean Start-Up than any other methodology, especially if you start including metrics for the artifacts you're producing and their use.

Commonly consists of a little documentation knocked up on a wiki, co-ordination of work through Google Docs or a whiteboard rather than an electronic project tool, and a higher focus on delivery over estimation and prediction compared to Agile.